# What does norm dd"0P in this series of Vim commands?

Tags: vim

I'm doing a Vimgolf problem to transform this:

```
First:
        Junk text.
Second:
        Junk text.
Third:
        Junk text.
Last:
        Copy these lines,
        and replace the text
        in each heading above.
```

to this:

```
First:
        Copy these lines,
        and replace the text
        in each heading above.
Second:
        Copy these lines,
        and replace the text
        in each heading above.
Third:
        Copy these lines,
        and replace the text
        in each heading above.
Last:
        Copy these lines,
        and replace the text
        in each heading above.
```

One solution is:

```
:8,$y<CR>:g/J/norm dd"0P<CR>ZZ
```

What is `:g/J/norm dd"0P` doing?  I understand that "J" joins lines, and ":g" is global, but I don't understand the rest.

Comment: Here 'J' is not  joining lines! It matches the lines that includes *J*. second part of global command is the pattern to match the lines.

Answer (score 6):

By pieces:

- `"0P` - Paste the originally yanked line from register 0. As read in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26716
- `dd` - delete current line

So this replaces the current line with the yanked block.